# Find and remove spyware via xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

According to iOS 8 I've read an article that suggests that it's possible to find and remove spyware / hidden software on my iOS device.

Does anyone has an idea how this exactly works?

I don't find any information about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can get spyware/hidden software on your device...?

Comment: Where is that article link?

Comment: This is what I thought too. But this is what the article says: "According to security experts, the hidden programs running in the background on the iPhone without jailbreak, if the respective app is signed with an Enterprise Certificate. Users can see the "invisible" software either on the home screen of iPhone or iPad, or in iTunes. If you suspect users of Apple devices should use the Mac program Xcode for review. Xode recognize and remove hidden software on the devices." I've translated the article, the original is on german.

Comment: You could look at the Devices window in Xcode. If the writer of this hypothetical spyware/hidden software was careless you might find a crash log. What "security experts" are these?

Comment: I don't know these "Experts" ;-) but I found it interesting if there is an security leak which COULD make it possible to install software without the users knowing and how it can be found and removed.